# ERROR: for rca-org2 Cannot start service rca-org2: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345:

Tags: docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

```
ERROR: for rca-org2  Cannot start service rca-org2: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I am getting this error when i try to run docker-compose file which looks like this :-

```
  rca-org2:
    container_name: rca-org2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    command: /bin/bash -c 'fabric-ca-server start -d -b rca-org2-admin:rca-org2-adminpw --port 7055'
    environment:
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/fabric-ca/crypto
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=rca-org2
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=0.0.0.0
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
    volumes:
        - /tmp/hyperledger/org2/ca:/tmp/hyperledger/fabric-ca
    networks:
        - fabric-ca
    ports:
        - 7055:7055
    -
```

Answer (score 0):

After Research I found that the container rca-org2 doesn't have bash installed but it has sh so running the container with (replace /bin/bash with sh) worked for me. so now the new compose file looks like this.

```
  rca-org2:
    container_name: rca-org2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -d -b rca-org2-admin:rca-org2-adminpw --port 7055'
    environment:
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_HOME=/tmp/hyperledger/fabric-ca/crypto
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_CN=rca-org2
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CSR_HOSTS=0.0.0.0
        - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_DEBUG=true
    volumes:
        - /tmp/hyperledger/org2/ca:/tmp/hyperledger/fabric-ca
    networks:
        - fabric-ca
    ports:
        - 7055:7055
```